# importing 3ds max ( .max) file into blender

Tags: collada, blender

I got couple of 2 .max files that were created on 2008 version of 3ds Max. The files are really very simple 3d models of room and furniture item.

I am using blender 2.53 beta.

I have 3ds Max 2011 version. Using this version I exported the model to Autodesk Collada (.dae file) and also to .OBJ files but neither work with blender 2.53. In blender I can import the files but most details are gone and wall edges look like annoying zig zag pattern and look worse than a silly cartoon.

Even tried exporting to old .3ds format but that gives more problems.

I looked at 3ds max collada plugin :
http://update.multiverse.net/wiki/in...COLLADA_Plugin
but it is not compatible with 3ds Max 2011 version.

So I am confused what to do as I am new to blender and 3d. What is the best way to export from 3ds max when opening exisitng 3ds max 2008 version models and importing to blender 2.53?

The models have simple lights and no animation is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to export 3DSMAX files is with a plugin (or script) running inside of 3DSMAX itself.  The Collada file *should* be the way to go, and maybe the Blender importer is just incorrect.  OBJ and 3DS files are very simple and should Just Work, maybe you can export to OBJ and edit it by hand to "fix" problem areas?  (It's just a text file so you can edit it in a text editor.)